# Select several input files Python Flask application

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to select several input files in my flask application, when I want to have an array list of my selected input files, the array is empty. How can I fix that ?

## HTML

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h6>Select files:</h6> <input type="file" name="inputfiles[]" multiple=""><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class=" form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light text-primary" >GO</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

## Python

```
@app.route('/gp_bagging_several_apps', methods=['POST','GET'])
def gp_bagging_several_apps():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("HELLO")
        f = request.files.getlist("inputfiles[]")
        print(f)
```

I also tried with `"inputfiles"` instead of `"insteadfiles[]"`. I had the same problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your `input` tag, you should have `multiple`. In your `form` tag, have `action` and `enctype`.

You can try something like below:

```
<form action="{% url 'function' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="file" name="files" required multiple/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-large"/></p>
</form>
```

And in the function:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    files = request.FILES.getlist('files')
    for file in files:
        # process your file
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't find the official doc, how can I get the file name instead of : <FileStorage: u'com.whatsapp.apk' ('application/octet-stream')> in my loop ?

Comment: you mean the filenames of the files submitted? can you give this a try: `file.name`?

Comment: No file.name gave me the name of the HTML input tag